# Почему мой ответ был удален?

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, ответы, удаление-ответов

Для чего и с какой целью вы удаляете ответы [как например этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/417547/) — я там явно показал что будет, когда сделают или применят мои стили и до этих пор не исправлено — смотря на сайт по ссылке — а вы удаляете.

---

Второй вопрос: как писать здесь личное сообщение?

Ответ на этот вопрос есть здесь: [Как задать вопрос напрямую участнику stackoverflow?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/440/181472)

Comment: > как писать здесь личное сообщение?

никак, если только юзер в своем профиле не покажет свой адрес почты. У вас, кстати, в профиле ничего нет.

Comment: на каждом сайте - есть такое - переписка и не обязательно что только через email - просто через личный кабинет - это здесь что то это го нет

Comment: Вероятно, вы не совсем понимаете формат StackOverflow. Это не форум в привычном понимании, где дискуссии тянутся неделями. Это не блогосайт со статьями и длинными вереницами комментариев. StackOverflow - это хранилище знаний в формате "Вопрос - Ответ". Важно задавать конкретные вопросы и давать сразу конкретные ответы (недостающую информацию можно запросить в комментарии к вопросы). И вопрос и ответ должны быть достаточно ценными, чтобы не только помочь спрашивающему, но и сохранить этот опыт и знания для миллионов пользователей Сети.

Comment: По этой же причине нет личных сообщений: они не несут ценности для других.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Как уже было отмечено в [ответе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/215/6) @TheDoctor, ваш ответ невозможно как-либо использовать. Stack Overflow, в первую очередь, - это база прикладных решений. Конкретно упомянутый вами ответ не является решением, как результат, был удален.

**Обновление**

Удалить, закрыть или оставить сообщение "как есть" решает сообщество. Исключительно по своей инициативе модераторы удаляют очень редко. В основном если сообщение не соответствует стандартам оформления (включая правила правописания).

Глобально, если сообщение не соответствует правилам, его можно:

1. поправить самостоятельно;
2. попросить поправить автора;
3. удалить.

Если говорить про конкретный ответ, то скорее всего, его было проще удалить, чем исправлять. Именно поэтому сообщество голосовало за его удаление.

Comment: Николай - вы удаляете вопросы которые не полезны по Вашему мнению - повторю - Вы считаете что ответ не полезен - и посмотрите на те топики которые написали новенькие пользователи - лично вы их не уважаете -

Comment: @LenovoID, обновил ответ.

Answer (score 5):

Потому что Ваш ответ не нёс никакого ответа.
Я не вижу никакого полезного для автора ответа, кроме того, что Вы как-то пофиксили код ТС'а.
И вопрос этот для [Меты](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com) должен быть.

Comment: ну как же так ? там же видно было что будет

Comment: А толку что ты исправил? Фикс ты не предоставил же.

Comment: интересно получается - я сюда больше не зайду , профессионалов видать здесь много

Comment: Да ради Бога, испугал прям. Только ты сам подумай - какой толк нам, читателям ответов, от того, что ты где-то что-то там пофиксил, если не выложил сам фикс? А без толка ответы принято удалять.

Comment: Окей - вопроса о коде не было - можете удалять этот вопрос

Comment: Ну ты, парень, даёшь - кто же задаст вопрос только для того, чтобы его кто-то решил, но не сказал как? Да, только авторы учебников :)

Comment: Хорошо понял -  буду подробно описывать как я это сделал,  но всё таки я ждал ответ от автора топика

Comment: А какой ответ может быть на это? "Скинь исправленный код."? Это надо было сразу сделать, это очевидно.

Comment: Несколько раз модэр удалял мой код - который после переписки в скайп оказался рабочим но здесь его не пропустили, как бы там не было я исправлюсь - раз мой косяк

Comment: @LenovoID, Ни разу не видел чтобы код удаляли. Даже откровенно тупой оставался - просто минусили и, со временем, удаляли как неактуальный.