# Как задать вопрос напрямую участнику Stack Overflow?

Tags: поддержка, вопросы

Как задать вопрос или написать личное сообщение непосредственно зарегистрированному участнику, если я знаю, что некто может ответить на мой вопрос, какие шансы, что он увидит вопрос, заданный через кнопку "*Задать вопрос*"?

Зашёл в профиль участника, но там нет кнопки "*написать сообщение*" или "*задать вопрос*" непосредственно ему...

Comment: никак. Здесь нет личных сообщений. Вопросы задаются всему сообществу

Comment: Как вариант, найдите его в других вопросах по сходной тематике и напишите комментарий к его комментарию или ответу.

Comment: @dreamChild Спасибо ребят!

Comment: Можно в профиле посмотреть, возможно там есть конактные данные.

Comment: Вы можете добавить комментарий к своему вопросу, в котором написать`@UserName`. Тогда пользователь увидит в своём inbox упоминание о себе. Но не нужно этим злоупотреблять.

Comment: @ixSci, только есть пользователь уже отметился в теме.

Comment: @Nofate, т.е. если пользователь не писал в теме, то через комментарий он не призовётся?

Comment: @ixSci, не призовется

Answer (score 26):

Вопрос задается не конкретному пользователю, а всему сообществу. Если ваш вопрос:

1. Соответствует требованиям: [ask], [help/on-topic], [MCVE](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  (это можно заметить по положительному балансу голосов)
2. Задан хотя бы пару дней назад,
3. Не получил решения,
4. ([И начать конкурс вы не можете или конкурс не помог](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/441/181472));

и вы считаете, что конкретный пользователь достаточно компетентен, чтобы дать ответ - попробуйте написать ему лично. Посмотрите информацию в его личной карточке. Возможно, там указан способ связи и круг вопросов, по которым можно обращаться.

Например, [Джон Скит](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) пишет вот что:

> Email: skeet@pobox.com (но сначала прочитайте, пожалуйста, [мою заметку о почтовых сообщениях, связанных со Stack Overflow](http://tinyurl.com/stack-jon-email))

Если такой информации нет, значит пользователь не хочет получать "приглашения" на вопросы.

Если вы решили обратиться к пользователю лично, напишите понятный текст. Объясните, почему обращаетесь лично. Вопрос дублировать не нужно, достаточно ссылки. Кстати, если окажется, что проблема не в недостатке экспертов, а все-таки в качестве вопроса, приглашенный эксперт может и флагов (тревог) понаставить.

Answer (score 13):

На Stack Overflow невозможно задать вопрос конкретному пользователю. Все публикуемые вопросы задаются всему сообществу. Если вы считаете, что вашему (или любому другому) вопросу уделили недостаточно внимания, пожалуйста, обратите внимание на [возможность начать конкурс по вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty).

Answer (score 8):

Выйти на диалог с конкретным участником средствами Stack Overflow можно, но общение не будет приватным. В частности, возможны такие варианты:

- Упомянуть ник участника в формате `@имя` в комментариях под любым сообщением, где этот участник присутствовал в обсуждении. Если сообщение написано самим участником - ник упоминать не обязательно (в некоторых случаях может быть даже запрещено), но уведомление всё равно будет ему отправлено.
- [Пригласить участника в чат](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6283/176217). Можно как создать новую чат-комнату, так и использовать существующую тематическую. Если участник уже был недавно в некоторой комнате, то достаточно просто там упомянуть его ник, используя тот же формат, что и для случая комментариев выше.

В любом случае, указанными вариантами не стоит злоупотреблять, особенно если планируется обратиться к участнику с новой задачей, не связанной с комментируемым сообщением. Вопросы, как уже было упомянуто в другом ответе, на Stack Overflow принято адресовывать всему сообществу.