# Кнопка приглашения в чат

Tags: поддержка, чат

Хочется понять как явно пригласить участника в чат. Например, @Grundy [имеет соответствующую кнопку](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40851708#40851708) в профиле приглашаемого участника:

> [image: invite]

Я же такой кнопки [не наблюдаю](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40851815#40851815):

> [image: no-invite]

В чём дело?

Comment: скорее всего ты только в одной комнате, а в этой комнате уже есть все те, кого ты хотел пригласить :)

Comment: Подтверждаю. Надо параллельно быть еще в других комнатах, чтобы опция была доступна

Comment: @Grundy я был в другой комнате, но это была комната-галерея (read-only) и в неё, получается, нельзя так пригласить. Это довольно странно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Во-первых, пригласить можно только в ту комнату, где присутствуешь сам. Во-вторых, участник должен отсутствовать хотя бы в одной из комнат, из числа тех, в которых присутствуешь сам. И в-третьих, для комнат-галлерей приглашаемый участник должен иметь право на запись в этой комнате.

Невыполнение этих условий приводит к отсутствию кнопки приглашения в профиле/меню участника.

Ну, и не стоит забывать, что участник может быть приглашён, только если он имеет профиль в чате (профиля на сайте недостаточно). Для этого вроде бы достаточно один раз зайти в любую комнату, вплоть до созданной автоматически при переносе комментариев под сообщением на сайте.