# Возможно ли продолжить обсуждение в чате по своей инициативе?

Tags: поддержка, чат, перенос-комментариев-в-чат

Когда комментариев под постом становится слишком много, система автоматически предлагает продолжить дискуссию в чате и предоставляет ссылку.

Допустим, в определённый момент времени я предполагаю, что с другим участником будет обширная дискуссия на узкую тему, хотя и относящуюся к теме вопроса, но всё же "не достойную" оставаться в комментариях.

Вопрос: могу ли я сам каким-либо образом создать комнату в чате и пригласить участника(ов) перенести наше обсуждение туда, дабы даже не начинать его в комментариях?

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Как задать вопрос напрямую участнику Stack Overflow?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/440/176217)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можете, для это надо найти профиль необходимого участника на StackExchange chat ([пример](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/233645/0xdb)) и там слева внизу есть  кнопка *"start a new room with this user"*. Искать профиль можно [тут](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users?tab=all&sort=recent) в инпуте *"filter users"*.

Условия наличия этой кнопки можно найти в [этом ответе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6283/398802).

Ещё, судя по [справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms), можно просто создать новую комнату и там будет кнопка "пригласить". Или вручную скинуть ссылку на этот чат нужному участнику.

Comment: Там есть профили всех пользователей SO?

Comment: @V-Mor вот этого не знаю. Возможно, новичков/тех, кто не писал в чат, там может не быть

Comment: Тогда возникает вопрос, как пригласить в чат нового человека, пусть и с достаточным рейтингом

Comment: @V-Mor судя по [справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms), можно просто создать новую комнату и там будет кнопка "пригласить". Или просто скинуть ссылку на этот чат участнику

Comment: @V-Mor https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6283/398802