# Задать вопрос конкретному участнику и получить ответ

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, репутация

Возможно, вы сочтете мой вопрос дубликатом вопросу [Как задать вопрос напрямую участнику Stack Overflow?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/440/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83-stack-overflow), но это не так. (кстати, интересно, тот, кто отметил вопрос дубликатом, прочёл только тему? А текст не читал?) Суть такова (**упор не на возможность задания вопроса конкретному человеку - всегда можно написать вопрос, а в комментариях выставить ссылку, а на корректность подобного**):

В уже существующей теме был затронут вопрос, не касающийся этой темы, но также меня интересующий. В комментариях вопрос не решить. Хочу задать этот вопрос отдельно и призвать конкретного участника, который знает на него ответ, чтобы он подробно ответил. Не будет ли это странным? Ведь, фактически, я устраняю сообщество от ответа (не факт, конечно, вдруг кто-то ответит лучше, но всё же велика вероятность, что первый ответ будет единственным и лучшим). Хочу избежать странной ситуации обвинения в накрутке чего бы то ни было.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как задать вопрос напрямую участнику Stack Overflow?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/440/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%bc%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%83-stack-overflow) Не вижу ни одного отличия. Стоит акцентировать внимание на отличия, если явно заявляете о том, что это не дубликат. Просто сказать "это не дубликат" недостаточно.

Comment: `Не будет ли это странным?` - тут имеются чаты https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=ru.stackoverflow.com  по C#, C++, F# и прочие - поэтому постоянно что-то мимо сообщества пролетает)) .........А в целом: почему бы не совместить две вещи - когда в чате поболтали и нашли выход - сделать вопрос с самоответом на ruSO?

Comment: ну просто так вы человека не призовёте) если он не комментировал до этого.

Comment: @pavel вроде бы можно призывать, если делал правки и без комментирования.

Comment: Проблема этичности такого поведения в том числе рассмотрена в предлагаемом дубликате.