# Как работают комментарии с указанием @участника?

Tags: поддержка, faq

- Кому я могу оставить комментарий с указанием @участника?
- Что нужно сделать, чтобы при добавлении комментария ответить конкретному участнику?
- Получит ли этот участник уведомление?
- Что означает фраза «упоминание (английское "ping") другого участника»?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод «http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/»</sub>

Comment: а вот этот [вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/440/186999) Не то же самое?

Comment: @Grundy На мой взгляд, нет. Указанный вопрос о том, можно ли задать вопрос на сайте напрямую участнику. Этот о том, как работает система уведомлений в комментариях

Answer (score 8):

Чтобы ответить конкретному участнику, вы можете использовать форму «*@имя участника*» в любой части комментария. При этом во [«входящие» указанного вами участника](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6981/208074) придёт уведомление. Если в учётной записи участник сделал соответствующие настройки, уведомление также будет отправлено [по электронной почте](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/10/improved-global-email-notifications/).

#### Кто из участников может получать уведомления?

- Автор сообщения.

  Автор сообщения получает уведомления обо *всех* новых комментариях к своему сообщению. При необходимости вы все равно можете использовать функцию указателя для наглядности. При этом, если на данный момент сообщение комментируете только вы и автор, часть *@имя участника* в начале комментария будет [удалена автоматически](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97098/eeeeek-what-happened-to-my-salutation/97099#97099), поскольку она не нужна.
- Любой участник, оставивший комментарий к сообщению, если его комментарий виден (не был удалён).

  Если участник комментирует собственное сообщение и до него комментарий к этому сообщению оставил только один человек, то такой человек [также получит уведомление](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82134/micro-refinement-to-notifications-for-comments-of-others-posts), даже если не указывать *@имя участника*.
- Любой участник, вносивший правки в сообщение (не применимо к правкам, ожидающим проверку, и отклонённым правкам).
- Для вопросов: модератор или обладатель золотого знака, который закрыл или повторно открыл вопрос. Если участник, закрывший или повторно открывший вопрос, *не обладает* правом решающего голоса за закрытие (то есть золотым знаком по метке или голосом модератора), то такой участник не получит уведомления.
- Для вопросов: любой участник, объявивший конкурс на вопрос (независимо от того, проходит ли конкурс сейчас или уже закончился).

Учтите, что при определении того, кому из участников отправлять уведомление, вопрос и ответы на него рассматриваются по отдельности. Например, если Петя — автор вопроса, он не получит уведомление о комментарии на ответ Васи (кроме случая, когда Петя *тоже* участвовал в этом ответе). Аналогичным образом Вася не получит уведомление о комментарии на вопрос Пети.

#### Почему функция автоподстановки не работает для некоторых участников?

Функция автоподстановки определяет, когда упоминание *@имя участника* не требуется, и в таком случае не добавляет участника в список предлагаемых имён участников.

Кроме того, в такой список попадают только имена участников, оставивших комментарий к сообщению. Участники, вносившие в сообщение правки, и другие участники, фигурирующие в истории сообщения, не будут добавлены в список автозаполнения, но вы можете отправить им уведомление, указав их имена вручную.

#### Могу ли я отправить уведомление сразу нескольким участникам?

Нет. Комментарии, содержащие более одного упоминания *@имя участника*, [блокируются](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2094/should-we-discourage-the-user-of-multiple-redundant-username-pings/2615#2615), за исключением упоминаний, добавленных с обратной кавычкой `` ` ``.
В последнем случае [уведомление будет отправлено](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2035/notify-user-when-their-name-is-mentioned-in-comment/35914#35914) только тому участнику, имя которого указано с помощью *@имя участника* первым. Например, для комментария *@petya `@ivan Привет!`* уведомление будет отправлено только Пете (если он принимал участие в сообщении), но не Ивану.

Исключение составляет случай, когда первое упоминание *@имя участника* либо не соответствует никому из участников, либо указывает на автора сообщения (и поэтому не является обязательным); в таком случае, проверяется следующий указатель *@имя участника*.

#### Можно ли изменить получателя уведомления после публикации комментария?

Если вы добавляете указатель *@имя участника* или изменяете его в комментарии, [уведомление может быть отправлено новому получателю](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40989/will-edited-comments-reach-addressees/74781#74781), если правка была сделана в течение определённого времени после публикации.

#### Существуют ли специальные ключевые слова для уведомления участников?

Нет. Такие указатели, как [*@op*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52368/does-op-also-notify-the-op), [*@downvoter*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37090/feature-request-downvoter-sends-a-notification-to-all-downvoters-for-your-post), или *@all* не имеют специального смысла и не приведут к отправке уведомления.

#### Каким образом выполняется соотнесение имён участников?

- В упоминании *@имя участника* часть *имя участника* должна корректно соответствовать [текущему отображаемому имени](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/481203#481203) участника на момент отправки уведомления. Предыдущие отображаемые имена участников использовать нельзя.
- Упоминание должно начинаться с пробела или располагаться в самом начале комментария. Соответственно, в упоминании [нельзя использовать знаки форматирования текста](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/39/whats-your-favourite-quote-about-programming/1079#comment-19850), например, выделение курсивом.
- Если первое слово в отображаемом имени содержит не менее трёх знаков, то упоминание должно совпадать с именем как минимум по трём первым символам с учётом регистра. Это значит, что для упоминаний *@а* и *@аб* соответствие с именами участников не будет найдено, [за исключением](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61960/allow-for-comment-reply-to-usernames-with-less-than-three-characters-in-first-wor/75809#75809) тех участников, у которых первое слово в отображаемом имени состоит всего из двух знаков. Например, указатель *@Ян* приведёт к отправке уведомления участнику Ян Иванов, но не участнику с именем Январь, а указатель *@Б.* отправит уведомление участнику Б. Гейтс, но не участнику Б.Гейтс. Если указатель *@имя участника* содержит более трёх символов, то с именем участника должны совпасть все указанные символы (ни *@vaska*, ни *@vasyapupkin* не соответствуют участнику с именем Василий).
- Соотнесение выполняется в обратном хронологическом порядке, то есть из пяти участников с именем Иван уведомление *@Иван* будет соотнесено с последним участником с таким именем. (Для различия участников используйте правило, описанное ниже.)
- При соотнесении упоминания с именем участника *из отображаемого имени* удаляются пробелы. Поэтому вы можете указать имя Вася Иванов как *@Вася*, *@ВасяИ* или *@ВасяИванов*. Последние два способа удобны, если среди участников также есть Вася Ложкин, отметить которого можно с помощью указателя *@ВасяЛ*. При этом вы не можете использовать пробелы в самом указателе *@имя участника*. Например, чтобы отправить уведомление участнику П Иванов, используйте упоминание *@ПИв* или *@ПИванов*. (Указатель *@П Иванов* будет обработан как *@П*, а это слишком короткое упоминание.) [Не удаляйте](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51911/the-dot-in-username-within-first-3-character-preventing-from-comment-replies/51913#51913) одинарные кавычки, точки, тире и нижнее подчёркивание.
- Специальные символы [заменяются](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48968/peter-works-for-peter/49409#49409) на более простые аналоги. Чтобы ответить участнику Piëre, можно использовать указатель *@piëre* и *@piere*, а чтобы ответить участнику Jörg, можно использовать указатель *@jorg*, [но не](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89051/joerg-works-for-jorg)  *@joerg*.
- Уведомление работает только для [текущего](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/481203#481203) отображаемого имени участника на момент отправки комментария, но не для ранее использовавшихся имён.

#### Влияет ли пунктуация на отправку уведомления?

Чтобы отправлять уведомления правильным образом, система игнорирует большинство знаков препинания, например, одиночную точку в конце предложения, запятую или двоеточие. Точные правила соотнесения не описаны в документации, но обширные тесты от 30 августа 2011 года выявили, что используется следующий алгоритм:

- Берётся первое слово, непосредственно примыкающее к `@`. Границы слова определяются либо по пробелу, либо по знаку, недопустимому в имени пользователя (например, `: , / ! ?`), либо по концу комментария.
- При необходимости из полученной строки удаляется одна завершающая точка `.` (при условии, что строка содержит более двух символов).
- Если после этой операции строка заканчивается на `'` или `'s`, такая часть строки удаляется.
- Получившаяся строка соотносится с именами участников с удалёнными пробелами.

Например, комментарий заканчивается упоминанием `@O'Conner's.)`. Слово, непосредственно примыкающее к `@` — это `O'Conner's.`, поскольку `'` и `.` могут использоваться в имени участника. Из этой строки удаляется завершающая точка и затем часть `'s`. В результате получается `O'Conner`.

Вот примеры поддерживаемых способов упоминания участников:

- `@имя любой текст`
- `@имя: любой текст`
- `@имя. Любой текст`
- `@имя, любой текст`
- `любой текст, @имя`
- `любой текст, @имя, ещё текст`
- `Любой текст, @имя.`
- `Упоминается в комментарии @имя's.`
- `@П.` как для участника П. Иванов, так и для участника П. Смирнов (в зависимости от того, кто добавил комментарий позже), но не для П.Иванов или П.Смирнов. Аналогичным образом, `@P. Smirnov` обрабатывается как `@P.`.
- `@псм` или `@псмирнов` для участника п смирнов
- `@Пет` или `Петя` для участников Петя Смирнов или Петя Иванов, соответственно
- `@имя...`

Примеры, которые **не** приведут к отправке уведомлений:

- `abc@имя`
- `*@имя*`
- `*@имя:*`
- `[@имя](http://some-url)`
- `@[имя](http://some-url)`
- `@П Смит`

Comment: >>Если участник комментирует собственное сообщение и до него комментарий к этому << комментарий или комментарии?

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин Мне кажется, будет работать одинаково как для одного комментария, так и для нескольких.