# Блок входящих сообщений

Tags: обсуждение, stackexchange

Что такое блок входящих сообщений? Как в него попасть? Что в нём отображается?

Answer (score 4):

*Данный ответ является переводом статьи Джеффа Этвуда «[New Global Inbox](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/28/new-global-inbox/)».*

*Важное замечание: оригинальная статья была написана в 2010-м году. С тех пор интерфейс панели входящих сообщений был значительно переделан, поэтому текст ниже имеет исключительно историческую ценность.*

---

Одним из неприятных побочных эффектов запуска [большого количества сайтов под эгидой StackExchange](//stackexchange.com/sites) стало то, что чем к большему количеству сообществ вы присоединяетесь, тем сложнее становится отслеживать все свои вопросы, ответы и комментарии. Согласитесь, это никуда не годится.

Поэтому я с радостью объявляю о том, что мы добавили глобальный блок входящих сообщений на каждый сайт нашей сети. Теперь на месте *аутентичного™*, [уже полюбившегося нам](//stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/13/network-central-stackexchange-com/) логотипа StackExchange в левом верхнем углу иногда появляется небольшой индикатор с числом:

[image]

Это число показывает, сколько всего новых сообщений было вами получено о всех сайтов [сети StackExchange](//stackexchange.com/sites). Под сообщениями я имею в виду:

- новые ответы на ваши вопросы,
- новые комментарии к вашим вопросам и ответам,
- @упоминание вас в комментариях.

Нажав на него, вы откроете собственно блок входящих сообщений:

[image]

В нём перечислены последние тридцать сообщений, адресованных вашей учётной записи, сопровождаемые:

- иконкой сайта, с которого поступило сообщение,
- заголовком вопроса, к которому оно относится,
- выдержка из его начала,
- сколько времени назад оно появилось (во всплывающей подсказке, так что наведите на него указатель мыши).

Нажатие на сообщение отправит вас на связанный вопрос.

Надеюсь, что этот блок упростит отслеживание собственных вопросов, ответов и комментариев по всей сети.

(и ещё, мы ищем способ формирования сообщений об @упоминании вас в чате)

*Примечание переводчика: после переработки дизайна кнопка для открытия блока переехала на правую сторону страницы:*

[image]