# Как вы поступаете, если вам не нравится оригинальный текст, но вы хотите оценить труд переводчика?

Tags: обсуждение, локализация, stackoverflow, голосование

У нас периодически появляются вопросы-переводы на мете. Частенько я не согласен с тезисами оригинальной статьи и хочу поставить минус. Но, в тоже время, я хочу поставить плюс за труд переводчика.

В контексте меты это ещё более запутано. Как вы в такой ситуации поступаете?

Comment: Потом бы ещё question бан не получить, из которого выбраться далеко не каждому удаётся :) А вообще, надо ответ добавлять "голосуй за перевод тут". Тут и знаки и мета-репа. Хехе.

Comment: @alexolut прям пикабу стайл - "комментарий для минусов"? )

Comment: Плюс переводчику, минус оригиналу — а как иначе?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov если плюсануть, то люди, которые не читают MSE, подумают, что плюсы в поддержку перевода.

Comment: @Suvitruf И правильно подумают, как мне кажется. Хотя, возможно, это спорные моменты.

Comment: В таких случаях (и во всех остальных) я использую слово "оригинальный" в значении "самобытный, своеобразный, непохожий на других", а не чертову кальку с английского "original".

Answer (score 3):

На Мете голоса могут выражать согласие/не согласие с содержимым.

Если переводчика волнуют минусы, то не стоит заниматься переводом непопулярных вещей. Дополнительно, стоит подумать, а следует ли "плохую" информацию вообще пропагандировать, делает ли это сайт лучше (если оценивать результат, а не приложенные усилия).

Answer (score 0):

Голоса на мете используются только для выражения мнения, согласия или не согласия с содержимым сообщения. Следовательно, если вы соглашаетесь с оригинальным сообщением (в изложении переводчика) ставьте плюс, в противном случае ставьте минус. Отдельного рассмотрения требует ситуация, когда перевод по каким-то причинам получился некорректный, нарушающий смысл оригинала, тогда стоит не голосовать, а оставить об этом комментарий под сообщением (или даже внести правку самостоятельно). Со словами благодарности за труд над переводом можно обратиться к участнику через [*ЛС*](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6289).