# Чат под профилем пользователя

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, чат, профиль-участника

У меня появилась идея создания чата в профиле пользователя на всем SE. Например если ты хочешь спросить пользователя о чем-то, не писать же в его вопрос об этом. И комнату создавать долго и неудобно. Так почему бы не создать чат под профилем? Это будет очень даже прикольно выглядеть. И удобно.

Comment: Для таких целей недавно был запущен сайт "ВКонтакте", пожалуйста, воспользуйтесь им

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как задать вопрос напрямую участнику Stack Overflow?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/440/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%bc%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%83-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SO - не социальная сеть. Личные коммуникации тут возможны только по инициативе модераторов. Если же кто-то готов получать уведомления по другим каналам, он просто напишет об этом в своём профиле: почта, скайп, телефон...

А если всё же очень хочется через механизм SO, то есть [вариант](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6289/176217).

Comment: Чат-комнату создать и пригласить участника всё равно можно. Так почему бы не упростить до одной кнопки?

Comment: @Qwertiy во-первых, этим могут, а значит будут злоупотреблять. Во-вторых, есть связь чат-пользователь → участник (то что называется parent user), но обратной связи, емнип, нет.