# Можно ли как-то подписаться на пользователя в Stack Overflow?

Tags: поддержка, профиль-участника, rss

Можно ли как-то подписаться на пользователя (добавить в друзья) в Stack Overflow или такого функционала нет?

Comment: Такого функционала нету. Можете попробовать обратиться к кому-либо сделав комментарий с @его-ник  в любом его ответе (или вопросе). Однако, такое поведение может повлечь тревогу, которой пометят подобный комментарий и как следствие --  ваш бан.

Comment: А зачем?       "Кумир, добей меня кодом!"  ©

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/440/262779

Answer (score 14, accepted):

На вкладке [Активность](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=topactivity) профиля любого участника в самом низу есть ссылка "лента участника".

> [image: лента участника]

Это [RSS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS)-лента, на которую можно подписаться, используя любые подходящие для RSS инструменты.

Comment: примеры "RSS инструментов": браузер, почтовый клиент (thunderbird), прямо в IDE (wilfred/emacs), Flipboard (ios), используя ifttt сервис можно сообщения в pocket, instapaper, telegram, etc отсылать.