# Почему бы не добавить возможность призыва пользователя в вопрос

Tags: предложение, упоминание-в-комментариях

На toster есть интересная штука, которая позволяет при создании вопроса послать уведомление конкретному пользователю, что бы он обратил внимание на вопрос.

Мне кажется, что такая штука очень полезна, ведь иногда бывает так, что ты знаешь того кто может помочь в решении вопроса, но в момент создания вопроса его может не быть на сайте, а когда он войдет, то вопрос может опустится на дно.

Разница с [этим](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/440/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83-stack-overflow) вопросом в том, что вопрос остается публичным для всех, но появляется возможность уведомить конкретного пользователя, который по мнению вопрощающего может ответить на вопрос.

**UPD**

Многие боятся, что их будут постоянно дергать новички, НО эти проблемы можно решить:

1. Ввести эту привелегию для определенного рейтинга
2. Если пользователь не желает, что бы его звали, то в профили можно поставить массовый игнор или игнор конкретного юзера
3. Чтобы по пустякам не звали какого-нибудь Джона Скита, можно организовать очередь проверки призыва. Так например, призыв Скита помочь отлдаить хеллоу ворлд до него не дойдут.

и многое другое можно придумать и продумать, что бы всех все устраивало.

В итоге, если кто-то не хочет это фичи, то может поставить массовый игнор и спать спокойно.

Comment: Я бы, например, не хотел, чтобы меня дёргали все кому не лень

Comment: @АндрейNOP но вот теперь все кому не лень могут дергать через этот коммент :)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как задать вопрос напрямую участнику Stack Overflow?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/440/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%bc%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%83-stack-overflow)

Comment: @АндрейNOP ну можно же все продумать. Добавить какой-нибудь игнор. Добавить мотивацию, что при прызыве и принятии вашего ответа дается дополнительные +N к карме. По моему норм же будет.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ вопрос немного похож, но о другом.

Comment: @iluxa1810 опишите различия в тексте вопроса в таком случае, чтобы это было более очевидно другим участникам.

Comment: Можно пингануть в общем чате, можно под любым постом участника кинуть ссылку. То, что Вы предлагаете потребует пересмотра этикета SO, это не то чтобы невозможно, но навряд ли будет выполнено.

Comment: @defaultlocale единственную проблему, которую я вижу- это призыв какого-нибудь Джона Скита на пустяковые вопросы, но и это решаемо через ограничения.

Comment: @defaultlocale, не все в общем чате сидят, а засорять комментарии к ответам этого участника ссылками на совсем другой вопрос - вариант не очень.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, привет! =)

Comment: @iluxa1810 ну, скажем, не только Скита, а любого участника, который ответил на предыдущий вопрос новичка. Опять-таки, я не говорю что это в принципе нельзя реализовать: можно создать ограничения, сделать так чтобы не все всех игнорили, закрывать «личные» вопросы и т.д. Я говорю что SO в последнее время особо не экспериментирует с моделью Q&A.

Comment: @mymedia поэтому пишу «можно», а не «нужно» :) варианты действительно не очень и сработают только если Вы с участником хорошо общаетесь. Стандартного способа приставать к незнакомым людям на SO нет и это скорее хорошо чем плохо.

Comment: @iluxa1810 Кстати, не знаете есть ли в тостере ограничения и если есть то как они работают?

Comment: @iluxa1810 Насчет +N к карме — это уже конкурс. Почти все активные участники постоянно просматривают вопросы с конкурсами, и пользователь, которого вы хотите призвать, точно просмотрит конкурс со своей меткой.

Comment: @ʞɔᴉNɹǝꓥ, я очень редко заглядываю в конкурсные вопросы.

Answer (score 14):

Потому что я, к примеру, ушел с Тостера в том числе из-за того, что меня звали во все вопросы подряд. Это не было главной причиной, но доставали меня такие призывы изрядно.

К примеру, однажды я ответил на вопрос "как запустить другую программу в Питоне". С тех пор я считаюсь экспертом по Питону, и меня могут позвать в любой вопрос про Питон...

Возможно, вы считаете что этой штукой удобно пользоваться для приглашения в вопрос именно того пользователя, который точно знает ответ. Возможно, так и есть. Но проблема в том, что ей совершенно точно будут пользоваться новички, которые поставят на вопрос одну самую общую метку, найдут в выпадающем списке случайного пользователя, и позовут его в надежде, что он вообще хоть как как-то поможет.

Куда эффективнее правильно оформить вопрос и проставить правильные тэги. А если вам совершенно точно нужен конкретный участник - вы можете выловить его в чате.

Comment: Если убрать понятие "эксперт" и зазывать только по конкретному имени, то это должно решить все проблемы, так как что бы кого-то призвать, нужно знать, что юзер может помочь, а что бы знать, что юзер может помочь- это нужно увидеть, что ранее он на что-то похожее отвечал в моих вопросах.

Comment: В итоге получится, что новички не смогут никого призвать, так как не будут знать кто может им помочь из участников, но в тоже время, те кто давно сидит тут, смогут по былым заслугам призвать конкретного юзера, так как ранее он помогал на чем-то похожем.

Comment: Можно было бы добавить настройку по отключению таких уведомлений.

Comment: @iluxa1810, по каждой метке можно посмотреть топ участников за месяц и за всё время.

Comment: @Qwertiy а зачем эта информация для новорега? Скрыть ее до определенного кол-ва кармы и проблема решена.

Comment: @iluxa1810, эта информация даже без входа на сайт доступна, к тому же, эти страницы отлично кэшируются. И ничего секретного на них нет. Пытаться их скрывать - только куча минусов и лишняя нагрузка на сервер. Тогда уж к самой фиче надо ограничения прикручивать, а не ко всему подряд.

Comment: @Qwertiy ну да. Я предлагал, что только пользователь с определенной кармой может кого-то призывать.

Answer (score 6):

#### Начнём с того, что такая возможность есть в [SO teams](//stackoverflow.com/teams)

Причём, любой участник может добавить в список любого, в том числе себя.

> [image: скриншот]

#### Теперь что касается обычного SO

С одной стороны я согласен, что при правильном использовании эта фича должна быть удобно. Иногда хочется позвать конкретных пользователей, потому что знаешь, что их эта тема интересует, либо что они с таким сталкивались. А то и вообще [вопрос задан по статье в блоге конкретного участника](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/762963/178988).

Но с другой стороны, что помешает всем подряд звать всех просто для того, чтобы им срочно ответили? "Караул, я тут ещё минимум в массиве не нашёл, а зачёт через 15 минут!!! Десяток топовых участников по плюсам - помогите срочно!!! ААААААА! Срооооочно!!!!"

Так что так себе идея.

#### Можно ли позвать участника в вопрос?

При особом желании такие способы есть:

- Обратиться в тематическом чате, если он там есть
- Обратиться в общем чате ruSO, если он там есть
- Позвать в один из этих чатов, если у него есть профиль чата
- Создать для вас новый чат, если у него есть профиль чата
- Написать комментарий под любым его постом на сайте (потом не забыть удалить)

#### Выводы

Такая возможность уже есть, но не надо упрощать её использование поскольку это вызовет неправильное её использование.

Хотя, возможность подписаться на некий вопрос самому, пожалуй, былo бы полезнo.

Comment: Ну "срочников" можно ограничить по привилегиям. Только участники с определенной кармой могут попробовать позвать другого участника.

Comment: Это какая-то модераторская SO 4 teams?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, это SO для команд: https://stackoverflow.com/teams. В том числе существует команда, в которую зовут всех модераторов - скриншот из неё.

Answer (score 6):

Я сначала хотел поставить вопросу "минус" в знак категорического несогласия, а потом придумал компромиссный вариант. Компромисс выглядит так:

- первый участник ("эксперт") у себя в профиле настраивает теги, по которым считает себя экспертом и не против, чтобы к нему обращались. Мотивы могут быть разные: например, человек хочет популяризовывать какую-нибудь редкую технологию, которую мало кто знает, и ответов по ней недождешься. А так будет сигнал заинтересованным новичкам;
- информация о том, кого по каким тегам можно дергать, скрыта;
- второй участник ("новичок") задает вопрос и ставит теги, а потом упоминает какого-нибудь другого участника. Если другой участник указал у себя в профиле, что он "эксперт" по одному из тегов вопроса, он получает уведомление. А если не указал - то не получает, это будет такой "крик в пустоту";
- как дополнительный вариант: "позвать" участника можно не сразу, а только через сутки, например.

На таких условиях я бы даже согласился на то, чтобы меня время от времени звали. А просто чтобы в любой момент кто угодно мог заспамить - однозначно нет.

**UPD**
Перечитал вопрос еще раз. Очередь на проверку - это перебор, конечно, лучше заменить механизмом жалоб и банов. Типа - позвали - жалоба "позвали не по делу" - "этот участник в вашем черном списке". Ну как-то так.

Хотя, при таком количестве разных нюансов, ограничений и прочего, самый простой способ - это указать у себя в профиле контактную информацию и по каким вопросам можно обращаться. И хватит с них.

Comment: Не, все можно продумать. Я об этих моментах еще в комментах писал, но решил их вынести в вопрос.

Comment: @iluxa1810 Да я тут что-то подумал - да ну в топку эти "призывы". Кто альтруист 80-го левела - может сообщить об этом в своем профиле прямо сейчас.

Comment: Ну это уже будет вне SO. А тут призвал кого-то в вопрос, он ответил и получил какой-то бонус и + сообщество получило какое-то новое знание

Comment: Вне SO будет только призыв. Если мне неохота каждые пять минут мониторить SO, я теоретически могу написать в профиле "если на ваш вопрос по XYZ долго не отвечают, пишите мне на мыло". Потом буду заходить, отвечать, получать плюсы и репу. Проблема только в том, что если мне лень или некогда самому мониторить SO, то и отвечать в такие моменты мне тоже лень или некогда.

Answer (score 5):

"На toster есть интересная штука" - так себе начало для темы на мете. Лучшим примером подобного функционала были бы [глобальные упоминания на GitHub](https://github.blog/2011-03-23-mention-somebody-they-re-notified/), но на GitHub это работает нормально, потому что

1. Гибко настраивается. Можно отдельно включить или отключить веб-уведомления и email-уведомления.
2. Есть опция "Block user", которая позволяет отключить уведомления от конкретного пользователя в случае злоупотреблений.

Если бы это было введено **именно в таком варианте**, я не против.

Comment: Ну по сути я это и имею ввиду.