# Как создать чат с конкретным участником?

Tags: поддержка, чат

Возможно ли создать чат с участником или группой участников?

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6289/15479. Не дубликат?

Comment: Зачем удалять то сразу)

Comment: Восстановлю), пока не нашел как создать чат

Comment: @Suvitruf я так и не понял, как создать чат..

Comment: Оформил ответом.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. К примеру, перейдите [на мою страницу в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/178012/suvitruf).
2. Там должна быть кнопка для создания комнаты.

   > [image: введите сюда описание изображения]